# Remove a row from MySQL table on button click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Ok, so I have this PHP code which creates a new table row for every row of an MySQL table:

```php
<table>
  <?php foreach ($cv as $items) {
    $counter++;
      echo "<tr class=\"tr\"><td>$counter. $items</td><td><button class=\"edit\">Editeaza</button></td><td><button class=\"delete\">Sterge</button></tr>";
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

And, I want to make it so that the delete button (which has the class "delete") removes the row with the corresponding ID.

I tried using jQuery and PHP to make this happen.
Here is the jQuery that I am using:

```
$(".delete" ).click(function() {
      $.get("delete.php"), {counter:  <?=$counter?>};
});
```

These are the contents of delete.php:

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$deletequery1 = "DELETE FROM persoane WHERE id = '$counter'";
$counter = $_GET['counter'];
$deletequery2 = "DBCC CHECKIDENT (persoane, RESEED, COUNT(*))";
mysqli_query($db, $deletequery1);
mysqli_query($db, $deletequery2);
```

conn.php contains connection details for the database, and that file has no issues.

When running the code, there are no errors, but nothing happens when clicking the delete button.

I'm not very experienced with jQuery or PHP, so if anyone can help me out that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand your point, but this will be a private website, and I also want to make all the features working before focusing on security, since that's not important at the moment, at least in my case.

Comment: It's not only about security. You have a bug in your code and there's no reason at all to do it the wrong way. It is easier if you do it properly. You will also fix the typo you have now when you reword this code. You have the wrong order of operations.

Comment: $counter  in not defined. You have to set it before use. So it has to be like this: $counter = $_GET['counter']; $deletequery1 = "DELETE FROM persoane WHERE id = '$counter'";

Comment: I moved it to after the include statement, and that didn't change anything.

Comment: I think your jquery is wrong - if you right-click and "view source" for the delete click handler, what value does it show for `$counter`? I suspect it will be whatever was the last value in your display loop. You need to change the delete function so that it gets the counter value for the appropriate button.